# How to filter a specific phrase that has a match in a array in a string

Tags: c#, arrays

just wanna ask.  Im a rookie in this so help me.  Please.

So, i have a program that listens to everything i say but when he hears "play 7 years" for example. He will start the music player and get the 7 years and get it playing.

So yeah.  The songs name is on a array so if it matches a specific word in the array it will get that phrase and put it in a string.  Please help me.  Im doing the best i can do to make you understand what im saying.

Comment: What are you asking about? 
Can you try providing more details like: 
What is the program you're working on? What do you want to do. At what point have you been blocked?

Comment: Ahm.  Im working with a personal assistant for my room that operates the lights and some other things like playing music.  So this

Comment: String[] musicnames = "7 years, rude, let her go"

Comment: I keep pushing the wrong button and then it posted. Sorry im knew to this

Comment: If input matches a string in a string array get it.  Then put it in another string

Comment: You haven't even told us what language do you use, maybe you can share some code too? 
Try to read your post as someone who doesn't know anything about you and your project - and see how hard is it to help you :)

Comment: Ohhhh sorry  hahahhahaha.  I use c# for my project.  My bad.

Answer (score 0):

This would be a lot easier if you had inserted your code so we all know where you start from ([check this out so you can help others help you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)), but I'm imagining your screen looks a little like this:

```
public void CheckArray()
    {
        var songs = new string[] { "Hello", "Heya", "Piano Man", "Seven Years" };

        if (songs == "Seven Years")
            // Play the song
    }
```

Then you'll need to iterate through the array, using a loop. I prefer a foreach, like below, that will check each one in turn.

```
public void CheckArray()
    {
        var songs = new string[] { "Hello", "Heya", "Piano Man", "Seven Years" };

        foreach(var title in songs)
        {
            if (title.Equals("Seven Years"))
            {
                // Do The Thing
            }
            else
            {
                // Do Nothing
            }
        }
    }
```

Hopefully this either sparks your imagination or gives you a better idea by what we mean by "Share your code" :-)